# XPath: Select Certain Child Nodes

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm using `XPath` with `Scrapy` to scrape data off of a movie website BoxOfficeMojo.com.

As a general question: I'm wondering how to select certain child nodes of one parent node all in one `Xpath` string.

Depending on the movie web page from which I'm scraping data, sometimes the data I need is located at different children nodes, such as whether or not there is a link or not.  I will be going through about 14000 movies, so this process needs to be automated.

Using [this](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=actionjackson.htm) as an example.  I will need actor/s, director/s and producer/s.

This is the `Xpath` to the director: **Note**: The %s corresponds to a determined index where that information is found - in the action Jackson example `director` is found at `[1]` and `actors` at `[2]`.

```
 //div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table/tr[%s]/td[2]/font/text()
```

However, would a link exist to a page on the director, this would be the `Xpath`:

```
 //div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table/tr[%s]/td[2]/font/a/text()
```

Actors are a bit more tricky, as there `<br>` included for subsequent actors listed, which may be the children of an `/a` or children of the parent `/font`, so:

```
//div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table/tr[%s]/td[2]/font//a/text()
```

Gets all most all of the actors (except those with `font/br`).

Now, the main problem here, I believe, is that there are multiple `//div[@class="mp_box_content"]` - everything I have works EXCEPT that I also end up getting some digits from other `mp_box_content`.  Also I have added numerous `try:`, `except:` statements in order to get everything (actors, directors, producers who both have and do not have links associated with them).  For example, the following is my `Scrapy` code for actors:

```
 actors = hxs.select('//div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table/tr[%s]/td[2]/font//a/text()' % (locActor,)).extract()
 try:
     second = hxs.select('//div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table/tr[%s]/td[2]/font/text()' % (locActor,)).extract()
     for n in second:
         actors.append(n)
 except:
     actors = hxs.select('//div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table/tr[%s]/td[2]/font/text()' % (locActor,)).extract()
```

This is an attempt to cover for the facts that: the first actor may not have a link associated with him/her and subsequent actors do, the first actor may have a link associated with him/her but the rest may not.

I appreciate the time taken to read this and any attempts to help me find/address this problem!  Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are only interested in textual content, not the links to actors' pages etc.

Here is a proposition using `lxml.html` (and a bit of `lxml.etree`) directly

- First, I recommend you select `td[2]` cells by the text content of `td[1]`, with expressions like `.//tr[starts-with(td[1], "Director")]/td[2]` to account for "Director", or "Directors"
- Second, testing various expressions with or without `<font>`, with or without `<a>` etc., makes code difficult to read and maintain, and since you're interested only in the text content, you might as well use `string(.//tr[starts-with(td[1], "Actor")]/td[2])` to get the text, or use `lxml.html.tostring(e, method="text", encoding=unicode)` on selected elements
- And for the `<br>` issue for multiple names, the way I do is generally modify the `lxml` tree containing the targetted content to add a special formatting character to `<br>` elements' `.text` or `.tail`, for example a `\n`, with one of `lxml`'s `iter()` functions. This can be useful on other HTML block elements, like `<hr>` for example.

You may see better what I mean with some spider code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

MARKER = "|"
def br2nl(tree):
    for element in tree:
        for elem in element.iter("br"):
            elem.text = MARKER

def extract_category_lines(tree):
    if tree is not None and len(tree):
        # modify the tree by adding a MARKER after <br> elements
        br2nl(tree)

        # use lxml's .tostring() to get a unicode string
        # and split lines on the marker we added above
        # so we get lists of actors, producers, directors...
        return lxml.html.tostring(
            tree[0], method="text", encoding=unicode).split(MARKER)

class BoxOfficeMojoSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "boxofficemojo"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=actionjackson.htm",
        "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=cloudatlas.htm",
    ]

    # locate 2nd cell by text content of first cell
    XPATH_CATEGORY_CELL = lxml.etree.XPath('.//tr[starts-with(td[1], $category)]/td[2]')
    def parse(self, response):
        root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.body)

        # locate the "The Players" table
        players = root.xpath('//div[@class="mp_box"][div[@class="mp_box_tab"]="The Players"]/div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table')

        # we have only one table in "players" so the for loop is not really necessary
        for players_table in players:

            directors_cells = self.XPATH_CATEGORY_CELL(players_table,
                category="Director")
            actors_cells = self.XPATH_CATEGORY_CELL(players_table,
                category="Actor")
            producers_cells = self.XPATH_CATEGORY_CELL(players_table,
                category="Producer")
            writers_cells = self.XPATH_CATEGORY_CELL(players_table,
                category="Producer")
            composers_cells = self.XPATH_CATEGORY_CELL(players_table,
                category="Composer")

            directors = extract_category_lines(directors_cells)
            actors = extract_category_lines(actors_cells)
            producers = extract_category_lines(producers_cells)
            writers = extract_category_lines(writers_cells)
            composers = extract_category_lines(composers_cells)

            print "Directors:", directors
            print "Actors:", actors
            print "Producers:", producers
            print "Writers:", writers
            print "Composers:", composers
            # here you should of course populate scrapy items
```

The code can be simplified for sure, but I hope you get the idea.

You can do similar things with `HtmlXPathSelector` of course (with the `string()` XPath function for example), but without modifying the tree for `<br>` (how to do that with hxs?) it works only for non-multiple names in your case:

```
>>> hxs.select('string(//div[@class="mp_box"][div[@class="mp_box_tab"]="The Players"]/div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table//tr[contains(td, "Director")]/td[2])').extract()
[u'Craig R. Baxley']
>>> hxs.select('string(//div[@class="mp_box"][div[@class="mp_box_tab"]="The Players"]/div[@class="mp_box_content"]/table//tr[contains(td, "Actor")]/td[2])').extract()
[u'Carl WeathersCraig T. NelsonSharon Stone']
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you very much for taking the time to reply!  I'm curious, and I will implement these things shortly to see what happens, if these methods will eliminate the issue of getting information from other `[@class="mp_box_content"]`, as that is one of the primary issues?

Comment: You will get only the "The Players" table content, not the other `[@class="mp_box_content"]` divs. I fixed `br2nl` with `.text` instead of `.tail`, otherwise some lines got overwritten. I also introduce a compile XPath expression, so that you can pass a `category` argument as an XPath variable, which represent the row's first cell's text you want