# Scrapy misses some html elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was using scrapy to get some data about books on amazon.com.
I just want the name, author and prices of the book. I wanna do this by category, for example computer science books.

consider the snippet of code(some amazon page):

```
<div class="a-row">
::before
    <div class="a-column a-span7">
         <div class="a-row a-spacing-none">...</div>
         <div class="a-row a-spacing-none">...</div>
         <hr class="a-divider-normal s-result-divier">
         <div class="a-row a-spacing-none">...</div>
         <div class="a-row a-spacing-none">...</div>
         <div class="a-row a-spacing-none">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a-column a-span5 a-span-last"></div>
::after
</div>
```

So, I tried to get the div elements inside of div[@class="a-column a-span7"]. But, just the first two div elements are returned. The command I used was:

```
>>> books = response.selector.xpath ('.//div[@class="a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right"]')
>>> abook = books[0].xpath('.//div[@class="a-row"]')
>>> prices = abook.xpath ('.//div[@class="a-column a-span7"]')
>>> len (prices.xpath('div'))
2
```

The code above does the following:

1. Get all div elements the contains information about a book on a specific page
2. Get the first 'book' and get the div that contains the prices of the book
3. Get the div with the class 'a-column a-span7'
4. Here is the problem: I don't no why the number of div elements inside the div with the class 'a-column a-span7'

I've tried different ways to get div elements after the tag < hr >, but It seems the scrapy stop on tag < hr >. I've tried used the following code also and the result just shows two elements:

```
>>> abook.xpath ('div')
[<Selector xpath='div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span7"><div class'>, <Selector xpath='div' data=u'<div class="a-column a-span5 a-span-last'>]
```

I spent some time and I couldn't solve this problem. I think it's very simply.

In this link: [stackref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433376/xpath-select-certain-child-nodes/18434243#18434243). There are some explanations about use tag < br > and < hr >, but It's not clear to me.

Comment: Can you provide the link from where you are scraping this ?

Comment: Yes. This is the link: http://goo.gl/9XoOt6.  THe page is in portuguese(Brazil).

Comment: Can't find the `hr` tag that is mentioned in the question. There are only two divs present after `class="a-column a-span7"`

Comment: The author is at xpath `div[@class="a-column a-span7"]/div[1]/a/h3/text()` and price is at `div[@class="a-column a-span7"]/div[2]/a/span/text()`

Comment: The `hr` tag is only present in few listings. Like the list 9 in the given link. You can try to validate it by printing the elements of the xpath `//*[@id="result_9"]`

Comment: @Rahul, this tag (hr) appears when the has a kindle version and paperback/hardcover version(in porguegues it's called 'capa comum'). Ok?

Comment: @rahul, I did a test here with a local file. The file just contains the snipped code illustrated in the post(with the necessary html code do not illustrated). And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you're facing can be resolved by attaching a `user agent` with your request. Try something like this and check your results:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.amazon.com.br/s/ref=lp_12008582011_nr_n_2?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A6740748011%2Cn%3A%218169561011%2Cn%3A%218169562011%2Cn%3A12008582011%2Cn%3A12008596011&bbn=12008582011&ie=UTF8&qid=1448202280&rnid=12008582011" -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'
```

Comment: Great! That's work now. Thank you! 
So, why it's necessary to used the USER_AGENT?

Comment: Some websites don't allow you to pull data so sometimes they block or limit data access to all the requests that comes from a bot which do not identifies itself i.e. don't have any user agent associated with it.