# how to create dict{} from <span> elements from CSS/Xpath selectors in Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```
> ['<p class="attrgroup">\n\n\n\n            <span>VIN:
> <b>5FNRL5H66EB107700</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n           
> <span>condition: <b>like new</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n   
> <span>cylinders: <b>6 cylinders</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n
> <span>drive: <b>fwd</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n           
> <span>fuel: <b>gas</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n           
> <span>odometer: <b>99000</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n       
> <span>paint color: <b>white</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n    
> <span>size: <b>full-size</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n       
> <span>title status: <b>clean</b></span>\n            <br>\n\n\n\n\n   
> <span>transmission: <b>automatic</b></span>\n           
> <br>\n\n\n\n\n            <span>type: <b>mini-van</b></span>\n        
> <br>\n\n    </p>']
```

I want to create key:value pairs between the  elements and the information within them.

Scrapy has a simple use of css and xpath selectors that define attributes into a dict object...The tricky part is the  tags can be up to 10 or only 1. So how could my logic account for all and for less, when they aren't all selected?

Thanks for the help and guidance, I'm new to web-scraping and Python.

Comment: HI Biilal Akhtar, to be frank, I don't really understand what your question is, if you can please clarify what you are trying to do. (It's even better if you can show what you have tried). Also, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe an answer lies in the following link, especially with the following line of code. If someone could help apply it to my code, I'd really appreciate it...I don't know how to use 'contains' xpath

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710360/11679948)  might have the answer.

`response.xpath("//ul@class='clg-info'/li[contains(.,'Ownership')]/span/text().extract()`

Comment: HI Biilal Akhtar, please don't post follow up to your question as an answer. If you need to add information to the question edit your question.